# Disable the "smoke" in SmokePing for multihost

Tags: network-monitoring, rrdtool

I'm running SmokePing to monitor the latency to several machines.

I have been playing around with the multihost feature, allowing me to draw stats of multiple machines in one graph.

However, on the details page, smoke is being drawn as well, resulting in this:

[image]

Is  there a way to disable this? As it makes the graph pretty much unreadable.

Smoke is enabled for the stats per server, so it's duplicated data.

Answer (score 2):

Well the whole 'smoke' part is pretty integral to the tool.  If you don't have any spread at all on the RTT, it's just a regular ping time graph, right?

The only idea I can think of to improve your graphs is to experiment with setting `max_rtt` to a very low number to cut off outliers.  You could also try setting `pings` to the minimum of 3, maybe that would give you less variation and nicer graphs.

For that matter, what about just setting up regular [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) and using a simple [ping monitor](http://www.foxure.com/howtos/ping-monitoring-mrtg) without all the fancy features of smokeping?  Or, set up [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) and use one of the several [ping monitors](http://matts.org/ping_plugin_for_munin) available for that monitoring tool.

Comment: I would like to have to smoke for every other graph, just the "multihost" graph (a sum of all selected servers, in a single graph) shouldn't include the smoke.